# Weight painting problem : when I move the head of my character,the cloak also move but it shouldn't

Tags: animation, rigging, weight-painting, rigify

I'm trying to weight paint correctly my character. It's a roman soldier. The problem arises when I move the head,because the cloak also moves with it,but it shouldn't. I'm using the rigify + pitchypoi armature. I don't know what's the deform bone that stop the cloak movement. Check the attached video for a better understanding. I have also added the blender file. Thanks.

[video](https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiJkZmQwZjQwNS02ZWRhLTRjYTgtYTlmYi1mNDc3MjY1YTNlYzIiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmlldHRvMjAwOEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ==)

[blender file](https://www.zipshare.com/download/eyJhcmNoaXZlSWQiOiJiN2NkMzk5Zi0yOTlhLTQyZDQtYjU2OS02N2NiMTEwN2Y3NTkiLCJlbWFpbCI6Im1hcmlldHRvMjAwOEBnbWFpbC5jb20ifQ==)

Comment: How do you want the cloak to be animated exactly ? Manually with a rig or simulated with a cloth sim ?

Comment: also you want to put back the "d" of download in the video's link so that it works for everyone.

Comment: I fixed the problem. Now when I move the head,the cloak does not move also. The solution has been to separate the cloak from the rest of the body going in edit mode,selecting all the vertices of the cloak and then pressing "P" and then "separate by selection" and going under the tab modifiers and removing the armature (rig) from the object field. This fixes partially the problem,because now when I move the head,the cloak does not move at all,but it should move a little,according with the movements of the head. Can I fix this problem using the cloth modifier ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simulate the cloak with the cloth simulator, you'll have to remodel it. This cloak was made for a still model, it was not meant to be simulated. Two points to keep in mind :

- A cloth to be simulated should have a non distorted starting shape, since the simulation will perform the distortions on it. If you leave the base mesh distorted, the surface will be completely uneven. It will look like some parts of the fabric are stretched.
- a cloth simulation only works if the cloth is single-sided. Your cloak has 2 sides. If you perform a cloth simulation on it, the simulator will still consider every face a piece of fabric. So you're basically telling it this mesh is a double cloak (except both sides are joined at their boundaries). To give thickness to a single-sided simulated cloth you have to use a solidify modifier after the cloth modifier.

As for attaching parts to your character, you have to combine pinning and hooking :

1. In pose mode, select the bone you want your pinned cloth to follow
2. Shift select your cloth
3. Tab to enter edit mode
4. select the vertices of your cloth you want to attach
5. create a new vertex group and assign the selected vertices
6. In the vertex operators (Ctrl+V), go in Hooks > "Hook to selected object bone"
7. Move the hook modifier on top of the cloth modifier
8. In the cloth properties, enable Pinning and select the vertex group you just created.

Here's a simple example of the result :

[image]

And here's the file used for this gif :
[image]